# How to convert MATLAB CNN to PyTorch CNN

Tags: matlab, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to transcode a MATLAB CNN to a PyTorch based CNN but I am not getting the same results.  In fact the PyTorch code is not learning anything.  The input is black and white images at a 64X64 size with batch size of 64.  How can I code the MATLAB code below into PyTorch?

MATLAB CNN:

```
boxsize = 64;

layers = [imageInputLayer([boxSize boxSize 1])

convolution2dLalyer(3,16,'Padding',1)
batchNormalizationLayer
reluLayer

maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)

convolution2dLayer(3,32,'Padding', 1)
batchNormalizationLayer
reluLayer

maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)

convolution2dLayer(3,64,'Padding',1)
batchNormalizationLayer
reluLayer

fullyConnvectedLayer(Nclasses)
softmaxLayer
classificationLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Small Matlab and Octave to Python](https://github.com/victorlei/smop)? It may works for it.